# DateTime.ToUniversalTime() gets ignored in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm develpoing an ASP.NET MVC application where I'm storing a `DateTime` objects in the database.

The webserver is placed in Germany and I'm from Denmark. The webserver is set to run UTC time.

When I save the `DateTime` object in the database, I store it as local time like so:

```
PeriodEndDate = billingTaskForm.PeriodEndDate.ToLocalTime()
```

I've even tried to set it to `.ToUniversalTime()` to see if it'll get stored as `21:59` instead, which was not the case.

(using Entity Framework)

The `PeriodEndDate` now has a value of `2015-10-08 23:59` in the database.

Now, in the running thread I'm specifying the threads culture to be danish, like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);
```

(The method which uses the `PeriodEndDate` date runs in it's own thread separate from the UI since it's an async, long-running task)

Later in the code, I'm using the `PeriodEndDate` to filter some contracts like so:

```
var contracts = firm.Contracts.Where(x => x.EndDate == null || x.EndDate >= periodEndDate.ToUniversalTime());
```

The contracts are stored in the database as UTC dates, which means that a contracts end date is stored as `21:59` so I need to match that date with my `PeriodEndDate`, but as UTC, hence why I made the `.ToUniversalTime()` call.

However, looking at the log, the `.ToUniversalTime()` call seems to get "ignored" somehow since the `PeriodEndDate` variable is `23:59` even if I did the `.ToUniversalTime()` conversion. It should be `21:59` if I'm not wrong?

Does anyone know why it's not converted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToLocalTime` and `ToUniversalTime` methods on the `DateTime` object are for converting between UTC and the local time zone *of the computer where the code is running*.  They do not belong in an ASP.Net application.  Neither does `DateTime.Now`.

Many servers follow a best practice of having their time zone set to UTC, so in these environments you will see no difference other than the change of the `.Kind` metadata property.

In general, in an server-side environment such as ASP.Net, you should not depend on the server's local time zone to be anything in particular.  Instead, you should use the `TimeZoneInfo` class to convert between UTC and a *specific* time zone.  For example:

```
string tzid = "Romance Standard Time"; // for Denmark
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzid);
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, tz);
```

Also, it's important to understand that time zones and culture are two different things.  They are not related whatsoever.

Comment: Matt, that's a great answer! Thanks a lot :-) makes sense. Is there, perhaps, any way to tell the entire application to use that time zone? It's important that everything datetime related is in danish. Thanks again !

Comment: No, that's not possible or desirable.  Again, "Danish" is a language, "da-DK" is "Danish as spoken in Denmark".  It does not at all tell you that the user or the server or anything is actually located in Denmark or should use  the time zone applicable in Denmark.  (I can also be a US English speaker and be physically located in Japan.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes perfect sense. I'll just set the time zone info globally on the class and use it to parse the datetime object as needed.

Comment: The best place is in your application logic, and the ID should be somewhere configurable.  If the logic needs "the time zone of the company running the app", then you can put it in a single location like a config file.  However, if the logic is "the time zone of the user visiting my web site", then you need to think about asking the user on a settings page and storing it in your database, retrieving it dynamically, or using a more creative approach such as pushing UTC down to the client and converting in JavaScript.   (You're standing on the tip of the proverbial iceberg...)

Comment: BTW - you might consider: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals, or just doing a lot of searching and reading here on StackOverflow on the [tag:timezone] and [tag:datetime] tags.  You might also consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) instead of `TimeZoneInfo` if you're doing anything serious.

Comment: Thanks again, greatly appreicated :-) It should definitely not be the user/visitor of the site who determines the time zone info, but rather the application itself. I just tried your code example and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try DateTimeOffset in C# and DateTime2 in the database

Comment: Have you tried using the static UtcNow on DateTime/DateTImeOffset?

Comment: Hi Rasmus, thanks a lot for your reply :-) So basically, a `datetime2` in MSSQL would be mapped to a `DateTimeOffset` if using entity framework?

Comment: I simply tried to log: `DateTime.UtcNow` which worked like it should :-)

Comment: SQL `datetime2` maps to .NET `DateTime`.  `datetimeoffset` maps to `DateTimeOffset`.  Yes, `DateTime.UtcNow` will work regardless of server's time zone setting.